# Find documents by populate match result in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

For Ecample, From this data with mongoose :

Data **Students** :

```
[{
  "_id": ObjectId("5afbb519a7fe344ff8db67e6"),
  "name":"Jack",
  "age":20
  ...
},{
  "_id": ObjectId("5afbb534a7fe344gf7db64e7"),
  "name":"Joni",
  "age":20
  ...
}]
```

Data **Activities** :

```
[{
  "_id": ObjectId("5afbb554a7fe344ff8db67e9"),
  "name":"Going to Market",
  "student": ObjectId("5afbb519a7fe344ff8db67e6")
  ...
},{
  "_id": ObjectId("5afbb784a7fe344gf7db64e2"),
  "name":"Playing with Friends",
  "student":ObjectId("5afbb534a7fe344gf7db64e7")
  ...
}]
```

I want to find a data base on conditions in populate with regex & This is what i am did :

```
let term = new Regex('Jack','i');        
let result = await Activities.find({})
            .populate('student', null, { name: { $regex: term } })
            .exec();
```

But the result is always return all data of **Activites** (The regex query doesn't work)

What Should I Do?

Answer (score 2):

You should try with using `match`

```
let result = await Activities.find({})
            .populate({ path: 'student', match: { name: { $regex: term } } })
            .exec();
```